# Highlight Links to content once clicked with a Tab menu

Tags: html, slider, sudo, nav

Hello I've converted the sudo image slider into a more of a content slider for my website and i want to the Nav Links (text) to be highlighted when active (on certain slides of the slider)

I've tried using:  "active selector" but it only seems to work with real page links like

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Home</a>
```

Opposed to the slider with this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="customLink" rel="1">Home</a>
```

Note: the menu is not within the slider.

An example of what i mean is like the menu here but just text: http://rbista.com/demos/zwin/ (this is using easy tabs i'm using sudo slider)

Can this be done in  css/html as i don't no JQuery ?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough

```
$(".customLink").click(function(e)
{
    $(".customLink").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

.customLink.active
{
   some css here
}
```

Comment: Hello where do i put:                     $(".customLink").click(function(e)
{
    $(".customLink").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});  and in what tags?